# The 5 key is being held down by a ghost?

Tags: keyboard

I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 plus wily-proposed and upgraded to latest packages.

When I leave my machine for approximately 30 mins and return to it whatever text entry widget has focus has the number 5 being repeatedly entered into it as if I am holding down the 5 key.

When I press a key on the keyboard (any key) it stops.

I have no idea how to debug this or what may be causing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds spooky! I wish I had something like that! :D

Comment: So who you gonna call? [Ghostbusters!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe93CLbHjxQ)

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard?

Comment: @VoodooBettie: Swapped out keyboard.  Will report if it fixes it.

Comment: Well at least it's not number 6... :P

Comment: Why 30 min? Is the trigger event a screensaver that comes on? Try adjusting the screensaver e.g. to 1 minute and see if that triggers it.

Comment: This is most probably a hardware keyboard problem.  What's the feed-back on swapping the keyboard?

Comment: Swapping the keyboard has fixed it, but they are not identical models.  The original was a Logitech wireless, the replacement is a HP wired keyboard.  My current guess is that it was a fault in the electronics of the Logitech keyboard.

Comment: Confirmed on one Samsung laptop, not on a System76 one. I have focus-mode sloppy set. I am still studying the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be the [same](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772854/the-5-key-is-fired-on-ubuntu-14-xx-15-xx-16-xx).

> You seem to have wireless Logitech keyboard, right? There was a Linux
>   kernel bug (not just Ubuntu distribution). It is already fixed with
>   kernel version 4.4.0-30.49.
>
> So you can just update your system with Software Updater for example.
>
> You can find more information here
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1579190