# The 5 key is fired on ubuntu 14.xx, 15.xx, 16.xx

Tags: keyboard

I'm on Ubuntu 16.10 (but appear in 15..).

Apparently without a motivation, my laptop key 5 being repeatedly entered into it as if I am holding down the 5 key.

When I press a key on the keyboard (any key) it stops.

I have no idea how to debug this or what may be causing it.

The same issue is on this post:

[The 5 key is being held down by a ghost?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699258/the-5-key-is-being-held-down-by-a-ghost?newreg=9dc023eb825b4292aef87b162de02af1)

Comment: Have you tried another KB as suggest in the other post? Another idea with the power off try gently lifting end depressing the 5 key - possibly take some canned air and blow around and underneath the key

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have wireless Logitech keyboard, right? There was a Linux kernel bug (not just Ubuntu distribution). It is already fixed with kernel version 4.4.0-30.49.

So you can just update your system with Software Updater for example.

You can find more information here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1579190